# Where can I find an old version of dropbox app?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, apk, dropbox

I'm using Android 2.3 and uninstalled dropbox. Then I wanted it back, but dropbox 3.01, the only official version available, is meant to work only from Android 4 on. Where can I find an old, trustable version of the dropbox 2.x that works for my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the most trustable source for older APK versions is [APK Mirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/). For Dropbox specifically you can find older 2.x versions here:

http://www.apkmirror.com/uploads/?app=dropbox

Comment: Thanks @Marcel. Unfortunately, the oldest version available there is 2.4.5, and it won't work with my gingerbread. Newest working version seems to be 2.3.11.4, which I downloaded from the I-don't-know-how-trustable http://dropbox.en.uptodown.com/android/download/53332

Comment: Another I-don't-know-how-trustable source: http://www.papktop.com/dropbox-2-3-11-4.html